# Asserting equality of notification object and managed object context in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

How can I assert that a given `NSNotification`´s `object` corresponds to a given `NSManagedObjectContext`?

This Swift expression won't compile and hence cannot do the job:

```
assert(notification.object! === managedObjectContext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwrap them and asset their equality by the following

```
guard let object = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext, object === moc else {
    return
}

if object === moc {
    print(object)
}
```

or

```
if let object = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext,
    object === moc {
    print(object)
}
```

Comment: I now went with `assert(notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext === moc)`. Thx.